# XNA: Reuse Content Project in another project within the same solution

Tags: xna

I have XNA Game Project (game) with (by default) contains a nested Content Project. 
I want to reuse this nested Content Project in another Project (game editor) in the same solution.

I've added Content Reference, but content files are not copied to the output directory (content directory is created but empty).

Somebody know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer...

The solution is to add a **Game Library** project and add a reference to **Content Project** to **Game Library** project. After that simply refer to **Game Library** in all the projects that needs access to **Content Project**:)

Some references: 
http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/35208/202471.aspx#202471